# How do I pass a list of Qs to filter for OR lookups?

Tags: django, orm, django-models, lookup

How do I pass a list of Qs to filter for OR lookups? Something like:

```
q_list = [Q(xyz__isnull=True), Q(x__startswith='x')]?
```

Without a list I would do:

```
Model.objects.filter(Q(xyz__isnull=True) | Q(x__startswith='x'))
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use python's reduce() function:

```
import operator
reduced_q = reduce(operator.or_, q_list)
Model.objects.filter(reduced_q)
```

Comment: Seriously. I love you. THANKS.

Comment: `reduce` is not a built-in in Python 3 anymore, so you can use https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce instead.

Answer (score 7):

Q objects also have an `add` method which takes another Q object and a Q connector (either AND or OR).

```
q_object = Q(xyz__isnull=True)
q_object.add(Q(x__startswith='x'), Q.OR)
```

I've found this to be helpful when constructing OR filters and I've written a longer example on my blog: ["Adding" Q objects in Django](http://bradmontgomery.blogspot.com/2009/06/adding-q-objects-in-django.html)